# List jQuery elements listening for a trigger.

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I find out what elements on a page are listening for a jQuery event?

I'm trying to write a script to move the tiles on the site: http://threesjs.com/. I tried to send a keypress event for the arrow keys, but it didn't work:

```
$('*').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress',{which:$.ui.keyCode.UP}));
```

and:

```
var e=jQuery.Event('keypress');
e.which=39;
$('*').trigger(e);
```

The tiles move when the arrow keys on the keyboard are pressed, and I should be sending this keypress to all elements, but the board doesn't react when executing this in the console. I think the best way to trigger board movement is to find out which element is listening for the key down event.

Answer (score 0):

A better way than manually triggering jQuery events is just to pull out the handlers into callable functions. Something like this:

```
function handleArrow(direction){
  // code here
}

// handlers for the keypress
$(document).on('keypress',function(){
  var direction = /*find out which key*/;
  handleArrow(direction);
});

// Manual trigger
handleArrow('left');
```

(insert standard globals and namespacing warning here) :P

Comment: Yeah, I understand that would be better, but threesjs.com. I'm writing JavaScript that will be injected to the website that will move the tiles. I do not have the source for this game.